# No "back" to translate

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, localization, responsive-design

On the ask question page for the responsive view the word "back" is not available to translate for use on international sites. Here is the screenshot of English based site to clarify:

> [image]

To see this "back" link you need to use mobile device in portrait mode or reduce window width on your desktop browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that. The string will be translatable with the next prod build.